# can't check string for digits and symbols

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I need to check string with 3 cases:

1. string contain only digits;
2. string contain only characters;
3. string contain digits + characters;

I wrote function, but it dont worc correctly. Can somebody help me with it?
I use JS+wdio

```
async function checkNumber() {
  const string = (await homepage.getStringText()).slice(15);

  expect(await homepage.getStringText()).not.equal("unknown");

  if (string.match(/[0-9]/) != null) {
    expect(string.length).be.greaterThanOrEqual(3);
    expect(string.length).be.lessThanOrEqual(14);
  }
  if (string.match(/[A-Z, a-z]/) != null) {
    expect(string).equal("n/a");
  }
  if (string.match(/[A-Z, a-z] + [0-9]/) != null) {
    expect(string.length).be.greaterThanOrEqual(10);
    expect(string.length).be.lessThanOrEqual(17);
  }
}
```

Comment: Only digits: `/^\d+$/`. Digits+letters: `/^[\da-z]+$/i`

Comment: It looks like you need to read a tutorial on how to write regular expressions. You don't use `+` to combine patterns, and you don't use `,` inside character classes (unless you actually want to match the comma character).

Comment: @Barmar yes, i have problem with it) thanks, you helped me

Answer (score 1):

I hope it can help you:

1. string contain only digits: `/^\d+$/`
2. string contain only characters: `/^\D+$/`
3. string contain digits + characters: `/^\w+$/`

To learn more about Regex, read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions)